# How to copy all hlsearch text to clipboard in Vim

Tags: vim

file.txt

```
abc123
456efg
hi789j
```

command

```
:set hlsearch
/\d\+
```

I want to copy highlighted text bellow to clipboard (or register):

```
123
456
789
```

Just like

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+' file.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can follow the below procedure.

1. Empty a register (for instance, `"a`).

   ```
   qaq
   ```

   or

   ```
   :let @a = ''
   ```
2. Run the command<sup>1</sup>

   ```
   :g/\d\+/norm!//e^Mv??^M"Ay
   ```

   If it is necessary to append a new line character after each of the
   matches, run this command instead:<sup>2</sup>

   ```
   :g/\d\+/norm!//e^Ma^M^[??^Mv$"Ayu
   ```

   Type `^M` as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>), type `^[` as
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>).  In order not to retype the pattern
   that just have been used in search, one can press
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd> to automatically insert
   last search pattern.

   Also one can record the command to execute on matched lines (the part
   following `norm!`) as a macro.  This allows to see the actions
   immediately on a sample line and to make sure they are correct.  Then,
   the macro can be applied using `:global`:

   ```
   :g/\d\+/norm!@z
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>  At the top level, the command is a `:global` executing the Ex
command `norm!//e^Mv??^M"Ay` on each of the lines that match the pattern
`\d\+`.  The Ex command begins with the `norm!` command to execute the Normal
mode commands `//e^Mv??^M"Ay`.  These are three commands separated by the
carriage return symbol `^M`.  The first one, `//e`, looks for the search
pattern (which is set to the pattern used in the global command) and put the
cursor to the last symbol of the match (because of the flag `e`, see `:help
search-offset`).  Then `v` command starts Visual mode.  The command `??` looks
for the last search pattern backwards (and put the cursor to the first
character of the match), thus selecting the text that match the last search
pattern.  The last command, `"Ay`, yanks the selected text appending it to the
`a` register.

<sup>2</sup>  The second global command resembles the first one in outline.
At each of the matched lines, it moves cursor to the last symbol of the match
and inserts newline after that symbol.  Then it puts the cursor to the start
of the match and selects (in Visual mode) everything up to the end of line
(including just inserted newline).  Finally, the command appends the selected
text to the register, and undoes newline inserting.

<sup>3</sup>  One can always see the actions recorded in particular macro by
examining the contents of the corresponding register using `:di z` or `"zp`,
for example.

Comment: it's very hard to understand `//e^Mv??^M"Ay`, could you please explain it? thank you

Comment: `??` is very uncommon. `qaq` is very good. I never seen before.

Comment: could you point where can I get more information about `^M`? thanks

Comment: That's some serious vim-fu in your global command.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @freitass: I believe, there is no description dedicated to `^M` code in Vim help.  `^M` is the escape code of the carriage return character.  To type some characters that could not be entered the other way (as carriage return here—pressing `Enter` key would not insert CR, running incomplete command), `Ctrl`+`V` is used (see `:help c_CTRL-V` and `:help i_CTRL-V`).

Comment: @a becomes a long string, and no newlines or white space between them.

Comment: @Kev: I didn't notice that you need to separate copied matches with newlines, as it is not stated strictly in the question.  Anyway, it's not any harder to take that into account (see updated answer).

Answer (score 2):

If your text obeys the pattern you posted you can start visual mode blockwise with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and select from `1` in the first line to `9` in the last line. Then you just copy to the `+` register, which is the system clipboard, by typing `"+y`.

Edit:

I have tested this new solution for the text:

```
abc123
456efg
hi789j
```

Replace all non-digit by nothing with `:%s/\D//g` and the result will be:

```
123
456
789
```

Copy it to the clipboard typing `"+y%`, then revert the changes with `u` and you are done.

Comment: it's not rect-block in most case

Comment: I think there is no way to append text to registers, the solution I found was by changing the buffer to the result you want and then undo the changes. You will have to type `u` just once to get to the original text.

Comment: I just figured out a long command `:g/^/call setreg('X', matchstr(getline('.'), '\d\+') . "\n")`. It's too long, there must be a simple one.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to extract all URLs, and append to the end of file:

```
:let urls = [] | %s/http:[^"]*/\=add(urls, submatch(0))[-1]/g | call setline(line('$')+1, urls)
```